# Are block diagrams valuable for non-LTI systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Do block diagrams provide any value in analyzing non-LTI systems? For LTI systems, block diagrams permit a powerful algebra for manipulation/reduction of a system. Are there classes of non-LTI systems (e.g. restricted classes of hybrid systems, restricted classes of non-linear systems, zero-order hold systems) where the structure of a block diagram also facilitates analysis?

Edit: I don't think I was precise enough with my original question. What I really want to understand is whether block diagrams are useful for proving properties (e.g. stability) of non-LTI systems.

Comment: Block diagrams can also be used for nonlinear systems. They can for instance contain expressions such as $\dot{x}=f(x)+g(x)u$.

Comment: I know that you can express nonlinear systems in a block diagram. But I'm struggling to see how block diagrams help one analyze a non-LTI system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

For example, Simulink code can be written in the this form. And block diagrams are used in the linear systems containing discrete and continuous parts, including holds and converters, in exactly the same manner as they are used in continuous-time linear systems.

Block diagrams are always more useful as a tool to describe and visualize a system than as a construction subject to explicit algebraic rules. For precise analysis and manipulation, system equations are almost invariably more precise and transparent. An example: in linear systems Mason's rules can be used to manipulate block diagrams and obtain transfer functions. Ultimately stability and other properties will be studied by looking at transfer functions. The value of formal block diagram manipulation methods is limited. Moreover extension to general, possibly nonlinear situations, is not easy.

Comment: I think my question wasn't precise enough, but I think you answered it anyway. I meant to ask whether block diagrams were useful for proving properties (e.g. stability) of non-LTI systems. Based on the second paragraph of your answer, I think that they are not useful for proving properties of non-LTI systems. Is that accurate?

Comment: I added a few phrases to the last paragraph. You may want to accept the answer if it satisfies your needs. (It was not a precisely formulated question in the mathematical sense, but it was certainly relevant and clear enough.)